# Why service_info is empty when using Python OneDrive sdk

Tags: python-2.7, sdk, onedrive

I'm doing my internship in a company has very high security settings, sometimes something in the network will be blocked without any notice. And I don't really have admin role for my computer. Right now I met a problem, and not sure whether it's my permission issue.

I'm trying to upload files in Python code to OneDrive for Business, it's the company account.
[This is the tutorial I'm using](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python), check that **OneDrive for Business** part.

Before uploading the item, I should pass the authentication.

I have tested my code line by line, it worked well,

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer
from onedrivesdk.helpers.resource_discovery import ResourceDiscoveryRequest

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
client_secret = '[my client secret]'
client_id='[my client id]'
resourceId = "https://api.office.com/discovery/"
auth_server_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize'
auth_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'

http = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
auth = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http,
                            client_id,
                            auth_server_url=auth_server_url,
                            auth_token_url=auth_token_url)
auth_url = auth.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
auth.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret, resource=resourceId)
service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)
```

until when I am trying to get the service_info, **it's empty....**

**Do you know why it's empty?**

**Or how can i keep writing the code here so that I could upload files to OneDrive for business?**

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that this is happening because our SDK drops all services where the `service_api_version` is less than `2.0`. Assuming that the service you are trying to access works with API 2.0, then you can use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40137811/556371) to get past your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. That code looks good, but the code I'm writing needs to be automated, so I cannot copy and paste the "code" generated by browser each time, this "code" will expire very soon too. So, based on that code, I modified my code, but no matter it's v1.0 or v2.0, I still get empty response['value']..... Here's my code: https://github.com/hanhanwu/Basic_But_Useful/blob/master/one_drive_buz_test.py