# Can't upload files using OneDrive API for Business

Tags: python, sharepoint, onedrive

I'm trying to upload a file to OneDrive of an MS SharePoint using [Python API](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python). I've succeeded in authentication, but I can't get any service_info returned.

I've already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981210/upload-file-to-ms-sharepoint-using-python-onedrive-sdk) and [here](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python/issues/60). I'm experiencing the exact same issues describe there. I've modified my code accordingly, but nothing seems to work.

Here's my complete code.

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer
from onedrivesdk.helpers.resource_discovery import ResourceDiscoveryRequest, ServiceInfo
from onedrivesdk.helpers import http_provider_with_proxy

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
client_id='xxxxxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxxxx'
discovery_uri = 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'
auth_server_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize'
auth_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'
proxy = {
    'http': 'xxx',
    'https': 'xxx'
}

import json
import requests
class AnyVersionResourceDiscoveryRequest(ResourceDiscoveryRequest):

    def get_all_service_info(self, access_token, sharepoint_base_url):
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}        
        response = json.loads(requests.get(self._discovery_service_url,
                                           headers=headers).text)
        service_info_list = [ServiceInfo(x) for x in response['value']]
        # Get all services, not just the ones with service_api_version 'v2.0'
        # Filter only on service_resource_id
        sharepoint_services = \
            [si for si in service_info_list
             if si.service_resource_id == sharepoint_base_url]
        return sharepoint_services

sharepoint_base_url = 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/'

# http = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
http = http_provider_with_proxy.HttpProviderWithProxy(proxy, verify_ssl=True)
auth = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http,
                                client_id,
                                auth_server_url=auth_server_url,
                                auth_token_url=auth_token_url)
auth_url = auth.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
auth.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret, resource=discovery_uri)
# If you have access to more than one service, you'll need to decide
# which ServiceInfo to use instead of just using the first one, as below.
# service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)[0]
service_info = AnyVersionResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_all_service_info(auth.access_token, sharepoint_base_url)[0]
auth.redeem_refresh_token(service_info.service_resource_id)
client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(service_info.service_resource_id + '/_api/v2.0/', auth, http)
```

I'm stuck at the 3rd line from the bottom. What am I doing wrong here?