# Load an excel file (office 365) with python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, office365, powerbi

I'd like to load an excel file which is located on my office 365 (education pack). After the data(frame) transformation I want to save the result on my office 365.

Today I have the following code on my local computer

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('/Users/xxxx/OneDrive.../cdm-test.xlsx ',sheetname='Form1')
...
df.to_excel('xxxx-dataclean.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
DOM_PRO.to_excel('xxxxx_PRO_dataclean.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

1- How can I read an excel file directly on office 365 (/test/cdm-test.xlsx) ?
2- How can I write 2 new Excel files directly on my office 365 ?

I read a lot of articles but nothing works as I want.

I hope you can help me

Olivier

Comment: What do you mean by "directly on office 365"? All your files will be stored in OneDrive. Either you need to connect to OneDrive (using OneDrive API) to access the file (or) you can sync OneDrive files to your local directly and access from that location.

Comment: I don't want to read excel directly from my local environnement (on my mac) but on line (https://xxxx-my.sharepoint.com/...). I tried  to read on Google spreadsheet, and it works. I want to do the same thing with an excel file online on One Drive microsoft. If you have an idea...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload file to MS SharePoint using Python OneDrive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981210/upload-file-to-ms-sharepoint-using-python-onedrive-sdk)